# which linux flavor (Centos, solaris, redhat ) is good for mysql server

Tags: mysql

I wanted to know which linux flavor is good for mysql, in the sense in which flavor of 
linux does MySQL perform best assuming mysql to be configured similarly on all flavors.

Comment: Err, isn't this the same: http://serverfault.com/questions/88815/which-linux-flavor-is-best-for-mysql-server

Comment: Yep, created before it was migrated from SO. To close as dupe.

Comment: Just for the record: Solaris is by far not a Linux flavored operating system and CentOS and RHEL (Red Hat) are basically the same. ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are only likely to be two significant factors, which aren't really technically driven:

1. Which OS are you most comfortable with administering.
2. What versions of MySQL are available through the native package manager of each.

The former may or may not be influenced by the availability of professional services support.